# Creating a DataFrame from elements of a dictionary

Tags: python

Below, I have a dictionary called 'date_dict'.  I want to create a DataFrame that takes each key of this dictionary, and have it appear in n rows of the DataFrame, n being the value.  For example, the date '20220107' would appear in 75910 rows.  Would this be possible?

```
{'20220107': 75910,
 '20220311': 145012,
 '20220318': 214286,
 '20220325': 283253,
 '20220401': 351874,
 '20220408': 419064,
 '20220415': 486172,
 '20220422': 553377,
 '20220429': 620635,
 '20220506': 684662,
 '20220513': 748368,
 '20220114': 823454,
 '20220520': 886719,
 '20220527': 949469,
 '20220121': 1023598,
 '20220128': 1096144,
 '20220204': 1167590,
 '20220211': 1238648,
 '20220218': 1310080,
 '20220225': 1380681,
 '20220304': 1450031}
```

Comment: yes, it is possible. where are you having trouble with this? Note that you'd end up with a dataframe that has 15,909,027 rows. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could help.

```py
import pandas as pd

myDict = {'20220107': 3, '20220311': 4, '20220318': 5 }
wrkList = []

for k, v in myDict.items():
    for i in range(v):
        rowList = []
        rowList.append(k)
        wrkList.append(rowList)

df = pd.DataFrame(wrkList)
print(df)
'''
    R e s u l t
               0
    0   20220107
    1   20220107
    2   20220107
    3   20220311
    4   20220311
    5   20220311
    6   20220311
    7   20220318
    8   20220318
    9   20220318
    10  20220318
    11  20220318
'''
```